# Вывести последовательность с разбитием по строкам

Tags: java, алгоритм

Необходимо вывести  последовательность (например алфавит от A-Z) по 4 элемента в каждой строке. Последнюю строку выравнивать пробелами или выравнивающим символом.

Comment: Открыть IDE, написать код и вывести.

Comment: Это невозможно. 26 на 4 нацело не делится.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 'Z' - 'A'; ++i) {
        if (i % 4 == 0) System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("%c", i + 'A');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Многомерный массив. В последнюю четверку добавить два пустых поля "" и должно сработать.

```
public class Main {
static String [][] al = {{"A","B","C","D"},{"M","N","",""}};

public static void main (String[] args){
    for(int i =0; i<al.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<al[0].length;j++){
            System.out.print(" "+ al[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Неоптимально. Если потребуется вывести в таблицу числа от 1 до 1000, тоже будете массив создавать?

Comment: Я понимаю, что не оптимально.  Пока способен решить таким образом. С числами проще чем с буквами, как мне кажется.

Comment: На самом деле буква это то же число, просто выведенное в другом виде. "A" это 65, "B" - 66, итд.